# Centrar los elementos de contacto junto al h3

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

estoy haciendo una copia de mi currículum online como práctica; ya casi lo tengo listo, pero tengo problemas para centrar los íconos de la lista de contacto en la vista de escritorio de manera que haya una separación entre ellos, la vista mobile me gusta como queda.

```js
//content of web

var data = {
    'en':{
        'profesion':'Junior Developer',
        'contact':'Contact',
        'objective':'Objective',
        'bio':
        'I am a person passionate about the development of mobile applications, wanting to pour all my knowledge into a company in order to continue training as a programmer.',
        'skills':'Skills',
        'education':'Academic Formation',
        'title1':'Mobile software development',
        'time1':'July 2019 - October 2019',
        'description-edu1':'Development of mobile applications using technologies such as: HTML5, CSS3, Javascript, Jquery, Framework 7, Firebase, Apache Cordova, Phonegap, design UX/UI.',
        'place2':'Terciary Urquiza',
        'title2':'Software Development Technician',
        'time2':'April 2019 - Present',
        'description-edu2':'2nd year student of the degree',
        'work-exp':'Work Experience',
        'title-work1':'INTERN',
        'place3':'Courts',
        'time3':'April 2016 - April 2020',
        'des-work1':'Attention to the public and management of files in Labor Court No. 5 of the Provincial Courts of Rosario.',
        'title-work2':'ADMINISTRATIVE',
        'time4':'March 2013 - March 2016',
        'des-work2':'Carrying out administrative procedures, telephone assistance and receiving visits, correspondence management, organization and filing of documentation.'
    },
    'es':{
        'profesion':'Desarrollador Junior',
        'contact':'Contacto',
        'objective':'Objetivo',
        'bio':
        'Soy una persona apasionada por el desarrollo de aplicaciones móviles, con ganas de volcar todos mis conocimientos en una empresa para poder seguir formándome como programador.',
        'skills':'Habilidades',
        'education':'Formación Académica',
        'title1':'Desarrollo de aplicaciones móviles',
        'time1':'Julio 2019 - Octubre 2019',
        'description-edu1':'Desarrollo de aplicaciones móviles usando tecnologías como: HTML5, CSS3, Javascript, Jquery, Framework 7, Firebase, Apache Cordova, Phonegap, diseño UX/UI.',
        'place2':'TERCIARIO URQUIZA',
        'title2':'Técnico en desarrollo de software',
        'time2':'Abril 2019 - Actualidad',
        'description-edu2':'Estudiante de 2° año de la carrera',
        'work-exp':'Experiencia Laboral',
        'title-work1':'PASANTE',
        'place3':'Poder Judicial',
        'time3':'Abril 2016 - Abril 2020',
        'des-work1':'Atención al público y gestión de expedientes en el Juzgado Laboral N°5 de los Tribunales Provinciales de Rosario.',
        'title-work2':'ADMINISTRATIVO',
        'time4':'Marzo 2013 - Marzo 2016',
        'des-work2':'Realización de trámites administrativos, atención telefónica y recepción de visitas, gestión de correspondencia, organización y archivo de la documentación.'

    }
}



//function to change language
function language(){
    $(function(){
        $('.translate').click(function(){
            var lang = $(this).attr('id');

            $('.lang').each(function(index, element){
                $(this).text(data[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);
            });
        });
    });
}



// function to change to dark mode

    function darkmode(){
        var body = document.body;

        var header = document.querySelector('.header');

        var work = document.querySelector('.border-work');

        var edu = document.querySelector('.border-edu');
        
        // body and header color change
        body.classList.toggle('bg-dark');
        body.classList.toggle('text-white');
        header.classList.toggle('bg-image');
        header.classList.toggle('bg-secondary');

        
        // border color change

        work.classList.toggle('border-work1');

        edu.classList.toggle('border-edu1');
    }
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif; /*
/*font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif; /*


/* Fonts */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arimo&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap');




/*Header*/
.header{
    /*background-color: #ff914d;*/
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.head{
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}


.bg-image{
    background-image: url(img/bg-header.jpeg);
    background-size: cover;
}


.cvphoto{
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.objective{
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}


.title-name{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

.title-profession{
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}






/*Objective and Skills*/

.title-objective{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

.skills{
    font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
    padding-top:20px;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.title-bio{
    font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.title-skills{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}


/*Education*/

.education{
    /*border-top: 3px solid #000;*/
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.border-edu{
    border-top: 3px solid #000;
}

.border-edu1{
    border-top: 3px solid #fff;
}

.location{
    font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 19px;
}

.description-edu1,.description-edu2,.description-work1,.description-work2{
    font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 19px;
}

.place1,.place2,.place3,.place4{
    font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.title1,.title2{
    font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 19px;
}


.comit{
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.terciary{
    padding-top: 20px;
}


/*Work section*/

.work{
    /*border-top: 3px solid #000;*/
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.border-work{
    border-top: 3px solid #000;
}

.border-work1{
    border-top: 3px solid #fff;
}


.time1,.time2,.time3,.time4{
    font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}


.title-work1,.title-work2{
    font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.courts{
    padding-top: 20px;
}


.adm{
    padding-top: 20px;
}








/*Contact */


.svgwhatsapp{
    fill:#25d366;
}



.svglinkedin{
    fill:#007bb6;
}

.svggithub{
    fill:#181617;
}


.whatsapp{
    background-color: #fff;
}



.linkedin{
    background-color: #fff;
}


.github{
    background-color: #fff;
}



/*Dark mode */







/*Contact hover */

.whatsapp:hover,.github:hover,.linkedin:hover,.mail:hover{
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="responsive.css">

  
  <!-- Css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <!-- Javascript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  <title>CvFranciscoBolatti</title>
</head>
<body onload="language()">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Header section -->
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 header bg-image text-white">
        <div class="head d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
          <figure>
            <img class="cvphoto" src="img/fotocv.jpg" width="150px">
          </figure>
          <h1 class="title-name" id="scroll">Francisco Bolatti</h1>
          <h3 class="title-profession lang" key="profesion">Desarrollador Junior</h3>
        </div>

        <!-- Contact section -->
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 d-flex flex-column text-center mt-3">
          <h3 class="title-contact lang" key="contact">Contacto</h3>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-md-column justify-content-around mt-4 pb-4">
          <div class="item1">
            <a href="mailto:panchobolatti@gmail.com" target="_blank">
             <svg class="mail" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path class="svgmail" d="M.026 24l11.974-11.607 11.974 11.607h-23.948zm11.964-23.961l-11.99 8.725v12.476l7.352-7.127-5.653-4.113 10.291-7.488 10.309 7.488-5.655 4.108 7.356 7.132v-12.476l-12.01-8.725z"/></svg>
           </a>
         </div>
         <div class="item2">
          <a href="tel:3413720055">
           <svg class="whatsapp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path class="svgwhatsapp" d="M12.036 5.339c-3.635 0-6.591 2.956-6.593 6.589-.001 1.483.434 2.594 1.164 3.756l-.666 2.432 2.494-.654c1.117.663 2.184 1.061 3.595 1.061 3.632 0 6.591-2.956 6.592-6.59.003-3.641-2.942-6.593-6.586-6.594zm3.876 9.423c-.165.463-.957.885-1.337.942-.341.051-.773.072-1.248-.078-.288-.091-.657-.213-1.129-.417-1.987-.858-3.285-2.859-3.384-2.991-.099-.132-.809-1.074-.809-2.049 0-.975.512-1.454.693-1.653.182-.2.396-.25.528-.25l.38.007c.122.006.285-.046.446.34.165.397.561 1.372.611 1.471.049.099.083.215.016.347-.066.132-.099.215-.198.33l-.297.347c-.099.099-.202.206-.087.404.116.198.513.847 1.102 1.372.757.675 1.395.884 1.593.983.198.099.314.083.429-.05.116-.132.495-.578.627-.777s.264-.165.446-.099 1.156.545 1.354.645c.198.099.33.149.38.231.049.085.049.482-.116.945zm3.088-14.762h-14c-2.761 0-5 2.239-5 5v14c0 2.761 2.239 5 5 5h14c2.762 0 5-2.239 5-5v-14c0-2.761-2.238-5-5-5zm-6.967 19.862c-1.327 0-2.634-.333-3.792-.965l-4.203 1.103 1.125-4.108c-.694-1.202-1.059-2.566-1.058-3.964.002-4.372 3.558-7.928 7.928-7.928 2.121.001 4.112.827 5.609 2.325s2.321 3.491 2.32 5.609c-.002 4.372-3.559 7.928-7.929 7.928z"/></svg>
         </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item3">
          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/francisco-bolatti-025021149/" target="_blank">
          <svg class="linkedin" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path class="svglinkedin" d="M19 0h-14c-2.761 0-5 2.239-5 5v14c0 2.761 2.239 5 5 5h14c2.762 0 5-2.239 5-5v-14c0-2.761-2.238-5-5-5zm-11 19h-3v-11h3v11zm-1.5-12.268c-.966 0-1.75-.79-1.75-1.764s.784-1.764 1.75-1.764 1.75.79 1.75 1.764-.783 1.764-1.75 1.764zm13.5 12.268h-3v-5.604c0-3.368-4-3.113-4 0v5.604h-3v-11h3v1.765c1.396-2.586 7-2.777 7 2.476v6.759z"/></svg>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item4">
          <a href="https://github.com/pancho95" target="_blank">
          <svg class="github" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path class="svggithub" d="M19 0h-14c-2.761 0-5 2.239-5 5v14c0 2.761 2.239 5 5 5h14c2.762 0 5-2.239 5-5v-14c0-2.761-2.238-5-5-5zm-4.466 19.59c-.405.078-.534-.171-.534-.384v-2.195c0-.747-.262-1.233-.55-1.481 1.782-.198 3.654-.875 3.654-3.947 0-.874-.312-1.588-.823-2.147.082-.202.356-1.016-.079-2.117 0 0-.671-.215-2.198.82-.64-.18-1.324-.267-2.004-.271-.68.003-1.364.091-2.003.269-1.528-1.035-2.2-.82-2.2-.82-.434 1.102-.16 1.915-.077 2.118-.512.56-.824 1.273-.824 2.147 0 3.064 1.867 3.751 3.645 3.954-.229.2-.436.552-.508 1.07-.457.204-1.614.557-2.328-.666 0 0-.423-.768-1.227-.825 0 0-.78-.01-.055.487 0 0 .525.246.889 1.17 0 0 .463 1.428 2.688.944v1.489c0 .211-.129.459-.528.385-3.18-1.057-5.472-4.056-5.472-7.59 0-4.419 3.582-8 8-8s8 3.581 8 8c0 3.533-2.289 6.531-5.466 7.59z"/></svg>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Navigation -->
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
  <div class="language fixed-top text-right">
   <button href="#" class="translate" id="en"><img src="svg/svg-english.svg" width="50px">
   <button href="#" class="translate" id="es"><img src="svg/svg-spanish.svg" width="50px">
 </div>
 <div class="fixed-bottom text-right">
  <button onclick="darkmode()"><img src="svg/dark-theme.svg" width="50px">
  </div>
 <div class="row objective justify-content-around">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4">
   <h3 class="title-objective lang" key="objective">Objetivo</h3>
   <p class="title-bio lang" key="bio">Soy una persona apasionada por el desarrollo de aplicaciones móviles, con ganas de volcar todos mis conocimientos en una empresa para poder seguir formándome como programador.
   </p>
 </div>
 <!-- Skills -->
 <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4">
  <h3 class="title-skills lang" key="skills">Habilidades</h3>
  <ul class="skills">
    <li>HTML5</li>
    <li>CSS3</li>
    <li>Bootstrap</li>
    <li>Javascript</li>
    <li>Jquery</li>
    <li>Framework 7</li>
    <li>Firebase</li>
    <li>Phonegap</li>
  </ul>
</div>

</div>

<!-- Education -->
<section class="education border-edu">
  <h2 class="title-education lang" key="education">Formación Académica</h2>

  <!-- Comit -->
  <div class="comit">
    <p class="place1">COMUNIDADIT</p>
    <p class="title1 lang" key="title1">Desarrollo de aplicaciones móviles</p>
    <p class="time1 lang" key="time1">Julio 2019 - Octubre 2019</p>
    <p class="location">(Rosario, Santa Fe, Argentina)</p>
    <p class="description-edu1 lang" key="description-edu1">Desarrollo de aplicaciones móviles usando tecnologías como: HTML5, CSS3, Javascript, Jquery, Framework 7, Firebase, Apache Cordova, Phonegap, diseño UX/UI.</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Terciary -->
  <div class="terciary">
    <p class="place2 lang" key="place2">TERCIARIO URQUIZA</p>
    <p class="title2 lang" key="title2">Técnico en desarrollo de software</p>
    <p class="time2 lang" key="time2">Abril 2019 - Actualidad</p>
    <p class="location">(Rosario, Santa Fe, Argentina)</p>
    <p class="description-edu2 lang" key="description-edu2">Estudiante de 2° año de la carrera</p>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Work -->
<section class="work border-work">
  <h2 class="work-exp lang" key="work-exp">Experiencia Laboral</h2>

  <!-- Justice -->
  <div class="courts">
    <p class="title-work1 lang" key="title-work1">PASANTE</p>
    <p class="place3 lang" key="place3">Poder Judicial</p>
    <p class="time3 lang" key="time3">Abril 2016 - Abril 2020</p>
    <p class="location">(Rosario, Santa Fe, Argentina)</p>
    <p class="description-work1 lang" key="des-work1">Atención al público y gestión de expedientes en el Juzgado Laboral N°5 de los Tribunales Provinciales de Rosario.</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Admin -->
  <div class="adm">
    <p class="title-work2 lang" key="title-work2">ADMINISTRATIVO</p>
    <p class="place4">Escribania Álvarez</p>
    <p class="time4 lang" key="time4">Marzo 2013 - Marzo 2016</p>
    <p class="location">(Rosario, Santa Fe, Argentina)</p>
    <p class="description-work2 lang" key="des-work2">Realización de trámites administrativos, atención telefónica y recepción de visitas, gestión de correspondencia, organización y archivo de la documentación.</p>
  </div>
</section>
</div>
</div>
</div>







<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qué resultado esperas?

Comment: Busco que en la vista de escritorio queden los elementos de la sección de contacto alineados en una columna centrados y con un espaciado entre ellos.

Comment: Una buena opción en contenerlos en un `div`, al `div` en CSS aplicar `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;`

Comment: Si ya lo estoy aplicando en mi código de muestra usando clases de bootstrap pero no consigo que queden bien centrados en la vista de escritorio.